# SoapUI - dynamic MockResponse returning values based on request

Tags: soapui

For testing purposes I need to have mock response in SoapUI that is returning dynamic values based on request. Namely I am sending in an ID of an object which I need to work with later in my program.

When I have groovy script like this:

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
requestContext.exportId = holder.getNodeValue("//Uwid_exp")
```

And part of mock response like this:

```
<Uwid_exp>${exportId}</Uwid_exp>
```

Then it works, when I call my mock service via SoapUI.

However, when I call the service distantly from my app, which is what I need for testing, then the mock service returns null value.

According to MessageLog the inbound request looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AKCEPTACE_PROTOKOL xmlns="https://ws.nrhzs.uzis.cz/NRHZS_WebService" xmlns:ns2="https://ws.nrhzs.uzis.cz/NRHZS_WebService/NRHZS_WebService.BussinesLayer.DTO" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <Ico>47114304</Ico>
      <Cpo>211</Cpo>
      <Uwid_exp>000119</Uwid_exp>
      <PDF_Potvrzeni>A</PDF_Potvrzeni>
    </AKCEPTACE_PROTOKOL>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But in the outbound part, there is:

```
<Uwid_exp></Uwid_exp>
```

I suspect that `mockRequest.requestContent` doesn't point out to the request in this case, so the script is trying to assign value to `${exportId}` variable, but there is none. But so far I was unable to elaborate what to put in `XMLHolder` object definition instead.

Where do I found the contents of the actual incomming request?

Answer (score 1):

So I find the solution quite quick elsewhere. The trick seems to be adding namespace into the script and then address the elements with it

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
holder.namespaces['nrh'] = 'https://ws.nrhzs.uzis.cz/NRHZS_WebService'
requestContext.exportId = holder.getNodeValue("//nrh:Uwid_exp")
requestContext.CPO = holder.getNodeValue("//nrh:Cpo")
requestContext.ICO = holder.getNodeValue("//nrh:Ico")
```